# How to connect with external file system via FileSystem class in Java 8?

Tags: java, http, java-8, filesystems, nio2

I found the following example of establishing connection with external file system using http protocol in [OCP: Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 8 Programmer II Study Guide](https://books.google.pl/books?id=bvYbCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA459&lpg=PA459&dq=how+to+connect+to+external+file+system+java&source=bl&ots=E15r8B7Wb1&sig=FnR6dEzEYL85I6itDejBixgCtMQ&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi47N728MPRAhUiJpoKHaErBm4Q6AEIXTAI#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20connect%20to%20external%20file%20system%20java&f=false) book:

```
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getFileSystem(new URI("http://www.selikoff.net"));
Path path = fileSystem.getPath("duck.txt");
```

But when I'm running this example, I receive runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "http" not found
```

Can anyone explain the reason of this exception? 
How can I run this example, to connect with external file system properly using FileSystem class?
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I can’t read that specific page of the linked book, but I guess, this is only a hypothetical example, not an example that is supposed to work out of the box. There is no pre-installed `http` file system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the NIO.2 API doesn't try to dictate how we should reference external file systems. For the local system, it behaves like the older API, but for external resources, I think the developers have to create their own custom provider fit for the purpose they need.

There is a starting point here: [Developing A Custom File System Provider.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html)